# Can this Recursive Solution be written up into a T-SQL Query using CTE or OVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Lets imagine you have the following table called Table1 of Orders in chronological order returned from an In-line UDF. Please note that the OrderID may be out of sync so I have intentionally created an anomaly there (i.e. I have not included the Date field but I have access to the column if easier for you).

```
   OrderID  BuySell  FilledSize  ExecutionPrice  RunningTotal AverageBookCost  RealisedPnL
   339      Buy      2           24.5            NULL         NULL             NULL
   375      Sell     3           23.5            NULL         NULL             NULL
   396      Sell     3           20.5            NULL         NULL             NULL
   416      Sell     1           16.4            NULL         NULL             NULL
   405      Buy      4           18.2            NULL         NULL             NULL
   421      Sell     1           16.7            NULL         NULL             NULL
   432      Buy      3           18.6            NULL         NULL             NULL
```

I have a function that I would like to apply recursively from the top to the bottom that will calculate the 3 NULL columns, however the imputs into the function will be the outputs from the previous call. The function I have created is called mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL and I have attached this below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fMath].[mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL](
    @BuySell           VARCHAR(4),
    @FilledSize        DECIMAL(31,15),
    @ExecutionPrice    DECIMAL(31,15),
    @OldRunningTotal   DECIMAL(31,15),
    @OldBookCost       DECIMAL(31,15)
    )

RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE(
    NewRunningTotal DECIMAL(31,15),
    NewBookCost DECIMAL(31,15),
    PreMultRealisedPnL  DECIMAL(31,15)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SignedFilledSize   DECIMAL(31,15),
            @NewRunningTotal    DECIMAL(31,15),
            @NewBookCost        DECIMAL(31,15),
            @PreMultRealisedPnL DECIMAL(31,15)

    SET @SignedFilledSize = fMath.sfSignedSize(@BuySell, @FilledSize)
    SET @NewRunningTotal = @OldRunningTotal + @SignedFilledSize
    SET @PreMultRealisedPnL = 0
    IF SIGN(@SignedFilledSize) = SIGN(@OldRunningTotal)
        -- This Trade is adding to the existing position.
        SET @NewBookCost = (@SignedFilledSize * @ExecutionPrice +
            @OldRunningTotal * @OldBookCost) / (@NewRunningTotal)
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- This trade is reversing the existing position.
        -- This could be buying when short or selling when long.
        DECLARE @AbsClosedSize DECIMAL(31,15)
        SET @AbsClosedSize = fMath.sfMin(ABS(@SignedFilledSize), ABS(@OldRunningTotal));

        -- There must be Crystalising of PnL.
        SET @PreMultRealisedPnL = (@ExecutionPrice - @OldBookCost) * @AbsClosedSize * SIGN(-@SignedFilledSize)

        -- Work out the NewBookCost
        SET @NewBookCost = CASE
            WHEN ABS(@SignedFilledSize) < ABS(@OldRunningTotal) THEN @OldBookCost
            WHEN ABS(@SignedFilledSize) = ABS(@OldRunningTotal) THEN 0
            WHEN ABS(@SignedFilledSize) > ABS(@OldRunningTotal) THEN @ExecutionPrice
        END
    END

    -- Insert values into Return Table
    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
        VALUES (@NewRunningTotal, @NewBookCost, @PreMultRealisedPnL)

    -- Return
    RETURN
END
```

So the t-SQL command I am looking for (I dont mind if someone can creates an Outer Apply too) would generate the following Result/Solution set:

```
OrderID BuySell FilledSize ExecutionPrice RunningTotal AverageBookCost RealisedPnL
339     Buy     2          24.5           2            24.5            0
375     Sell    3          23.5           -1           23.5            -2
396     Sell    3          20.5           -4           21.25           0
416     Sell    1          16.4           -5           20.28           0
405     Buy     4          18.2           -1           20.28           8.32
421     Sell    1          16.7           -2           18.49           0
432     Buy     3          18.6           1            18.6            -0.29
```

A few notes, the above stored procedure calls a trivial function fMath.sfSignedSize which just makes ('Sell',3) = -3. Also, for the avoidance of doubt, I would see the solution making these calls in this order assuming I am correct in my calculations! (Note that I start off assuming the OldRunningTotal and OldBookCost are both zero):

```
SELECT * FROM fMath.mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL('Buy',2,24.5,0,0)
SELECT * FROM fMath.mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL('Sell',3,23.5,2,24.5)
SELECT * FROM fMath.mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL('Sell',3,20.5,-1,23.5)
SELECT * FROM fMath.mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL('Sell',1,16.4,-4,21.25)
SELECT * FROM fMath.mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL('Buy',4,18.2,-5,20.28)
SELECT * FROM fMath.mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL('Sell',1,16.7,-1,20.28)
SELECT * FROM fMath.mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL('Buy',3,18.6,-2,18.49)
```

Obviously, the [fMath].[mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL] may need to be tweaked so that it can start off with NULL entries as the OldRunningTotal and OldBookCost but this is trivially done. The SQL Set theory of applying the resursive nature is a little harder.

Many thanks,
Bertie.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I think you'll get more bites if you start with something a little simpler than this. Seems to be a pretty complex question to not have a consulting fee attached to it.

Comment: @Bertie running total is not yet supported on Sql Server 2008's CTE. On Sql Server 2012 it's a very straightforward implementation. Having said that, you can opt for loop-based approach. If you use set-based approach on Sql Server 2008 and below, it will be very slow, that is if you have 100 rows, SQL Server will actually go back and forth on all rows 5,050 times. Loops should be avoided, but running total is one of the rarity cases where loop shines: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-redux.aspx

Comment: Another approach you could do is you create a temporary table or table variable, then you do `UPDATE tbl SET @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + Qty, RunningTotal = @RunningTotal`

Comment: You *will* need the `Date` column, or some other column(s) by which an `ORDER BY` can be defined which matches your desired order - otherwise, the results will be ill-defined. You may get results that *happen* to work when testing with small samples, but are not guaranteed to so work (and may blow up tomorrow on exactly the same sample).

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I have gone with John Dewey's answer as it was exactly the elegant answer I sought. I am not sure about the performance considerations, but I am quite likely to through this ins a cursor or a while loop as its one of the building blocks I am exploring. Aaron, FYI< I think I met you at SQL Bits this year and asked about the Query Analyser in SSDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark without fully functioning [fMath].[mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL] to test with. My track record with getting recursive CTE's right the first time before testing is only about 50%, but even if not perfect it should be enough to get you started, if I understand your requirements correctly:

```
-- First, cache Table1 into #temp to improve recursive CTE performance
select
RowNum=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY OrderID)
, *
INTO #temp
FROM Table1;
GO

; WITH CTE (RowNum,OrderID, BuySell, FilledSize, ExecutionPrice, RunningTotal, AverageBookCost, RealisedPnL) AS (
    SELECT RowNum,OrderID, BuySell, FilledSize, ExecutionPrice, RunningTotal=0, AverageBookCost=0, RealisedPnL=0
    FROM #temp
    WHERE RowNum=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.RowNum, t.OrderID, t.BuySell, t.FilledSize, t.ExecutionPrice
    , RunningTotal=c.NewRunningTotal, AverageBookCost=c.NewBookCost, RealisedPnL=c.PreMultRealisedPnL
    FROM #temp t
    INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.RowNum+1 = t.RowNum
    CROSS APPLY [fMath].[mfCalc_RunningTotalBookCostPnL](t.BuySell, t.FilledSize, t.ExecutionPrice, CTE.RunningTotal, CTE.AverageBookCost) AS c
)
SELECT OrderID, BuySell, FilledSize, ExecutionPrice, RunningTotal, AverageBookCost, RealisedPnL
FROM CTE
/* Replace the above SELECT with the following after testing ok
UPDATE tab
SET RunningTotal=CTE.RunningTotal
, AverageBookCost=CTE.AverageBookCost
, RealisedPnL=CTE.RealisedPnL
FROM Table1 tab
INNER JOIN CTE on CTE.OrderID=tab.OrderID
*/
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
GO

-- clean up
DROP TABLE #temp
GO
```

One more disclaimer - recursive CTEs are good for a max depth of 32767. If this is too restrictive, you'll need to explore either a different method, or some sort of windowing on the data set.

Comment: Thanks John, This is exactly what I was looking for. Excellent answer as I did not need to make any changes. Very elegant.

Comment: I made a post about running total using CTE recursion. You can take a look at it at http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/05/running-total-here-and-now.html Running total using recursion is not so desirable, it is very slow, on 5,000 rows, it took 9 seconds to show the results, the alternative approach took 0 second

Comment: @MichaelBuen - I agree that no one method is always the best solution. But I would be careful with blanket statements like, "recursive CTEs are evil and should always be avoided". I've heard this about views and triggers too. I've used recursive CTEs to solve a small percentage of problems, and what I've found is, performance is tied more to the maximum depth encountered, than it is to the total number of rows processed. For example I suggest exploring a scenario where your OrderIDs are divided among a large number of customers and the running total needs to reset for each customer...

Comment: I didn't made a blanket statement that **recursive CTEs are evil** and should **always be avoided**. But perhaps I made a blanket statement that running total using recursion is evil? :-) I just want everyone to be aware of the options, in fact I wanted to give cursor a shot and it might be faster and/or more deterministic than quirky update. So there, I hate blanket statements or any proof-by-blatant assertion, I'm not fond of them. If I am, I would not even recommend Adam Machanic's cursor approach, as many are saying **cursor is evil**. I  don't live by the soundbites ;-)

Comment: Right, I should have clarified the running total context. I didn't mean to suggest you think only in bumper stickers and 8-sec soundbites like too many others do. Yes, the TIMTOWTDE rule applies to running totals. My point about recursive CTE performance is the recursion depth, especially where you have the added complexity the running total frequently. I know several ways to handle such grouped running totals, including cursors, but I have found the recursive approach to actually be quite fast when the recursion depth remains relatively shallow.

Comment: "For example I suggest exploring a scenario where your OrderIDs are divided among a large number of customers and the running total needs to reset for each customer" I now put a customer partition on 5,000 rows, on four customers, the running total resets on each customer. With four customers, the 9 seconds performance drops to 49 seconds; with eight customers, it's still the same speed(50 seconds actually). I'm not seeing that making the depth shallower could make the query faster http://stackoverflow.com/a/10788666

Comment: Hmm.. now I know where your speed come from. I tried  materializing the row numbering to an actual table(`select * into #temp`). You're right, it's fast

Comment: That was the first big obticle I had to overcome the first time I used a recursive CTE. Using another CTE for the source can be deadly for large data sets.

Answer (score 4):

#### Running total. UPDATE temp table vs CTE

```
create table Test(
    OrderID int primary key,
    Qty int not null
);



declare @i int = 1;

while @i <= 5000 begin
    insert into Test(OrderID, Qty) values (@i * 2,rand() * 10); 
    set @i = @i + 1;
end;
```

**Recursive solution** takes 9 seconds:

```
with T AS
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by OrderID) as rn, * from test
)
,R(Rn, OrderId, Qty, RunningTotal) as
(
    select Rn, OrderID, Qty, Qty
    from t 
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select t.Rn, t.OrderId, t.Qty, p.RunningTotal + t.Qty
    from t t
    join r p on t.rn = p.rn + 1

)
select R.OrderId, R.Qty, R.RunningTotal from r
option(maxrecursion 0);
```

**UPDATE table** takes 0 second:

```
create function TestRunningTotal()
returns @ReturnTable table(
    OrderId int, Qty int, RunningTotal int
)
as begin

    insert into @ReturnTable(OrderID, Qty, RunningTotal)
    select OrderID, Qty, 0 from Test
    order by OrderID;

    declare @RunningTotal int = 0;

    update @ReturnTable set 
           RunningTotal = @RunningTotal, 
           @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + Qty;

    return;
end;
```

Those two approaches could at least give you a framework to build your query upon.

---

BTW in SQL Server, unlike in MySQL, the order of variable assignment doesn't matter. This:

```
update @ReturnTable set 
    RunningTotal = @RunningTotal, 
    @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + Qty;
```

And the following:

```
update @ReturnTable set 
    @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + Qty,
    RunningTotal = @RunningTotal;
```

They both execute the same way, i.e. the variable assignments happen first, regardless of variable assignment's position in the statement. Both queries have these same output:

```
OrderId     Qty         RunningTotal
----------- ----------- ------------
2           4           4
4           8           12
6           4           16
8           5           21
10          3           24
12          8           32
14          2           34
16          9           43
18          1           44
20          2           46
22          0           46
24          2           48
26          6           54
```

On your exact table, just detect Buy/Sell, you can either multiply it by 1 and -1 respectively, or you merely sign the fields, e.g. :

```
update @ReturnTable set 
       @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + 
                       CASE WHEN BuySell = 'Buy' THEN Qty ELSE -Qty END,
       RunningTotal = @RunningTotal;
```

---

If you happen to upgrade to SQL Server 2012, here's the straightforward implementation of running total:

```
select OrderID, Qty, sum(Qty) over(order by OrderID) as RunningTotal
from Test
```

On your exact problem:

```
select OrderID, Qty, 

   sum(CASE WHEN BuySell = 'Buy' THEN Qty ELSE -Qty END) 
   over(order by OrderID) as RunningTotal

from Test;
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you feel uneasy with [quirky update](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/5150/please-can-somebody-explain-how-quirky-updates-wor.html), you can put a guard clause to check if the order of to-be-updated rows matches the original order(aided by identity(1,1)):

```
create function TestRunningTotalGuarded()
returns @ReturnTable table(
    OrderId int, Qty int, 
    RunningTotal int not null, 
    RN int identity(1,1) not null
)
as begin

    insert into @ReturnTable(OrderID, Qty, RunningTotal)
    select OrderID, Qty, 0 from Test
    order by OrderID;

    declare @RunningTotal int = 0;

    declare @RN_check INT = 0;

    update @ReturnTable set 
            @RN_check = @RN_check + 1,
            @RunningTotal = 
                (case when RN = @RN_check then @RunningTotal + Qty else 1/0 end),
            RunningTotal = @RunningTotal;

    return;

end;
```

If UPDATE really update rows in unpredictable order (or by any chance it will), the @RN_Check will not be equal to RN(identity order) anymore, the code will raise a **divide-by-zero error** then. Using guard clause, unpredictable update order will [fail fast](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FailFast); if this happen then, it will be the time to file a <strike>bug</strike> petition to Microsoft to make the quirky update not so quirky :-)

The guard clause hedge on the inherently imperative operation(variable assignment) is really sequential.

Comment: The part where you are saying that the order of assignments in an UPDATE statement is unimportant doesn't seem to illustrate your point well. :) (You probably forgot to swap the lines.) Anyway, the *quirky update* method is unreliable, because you can't guarantee the order of updates.

Comment: Regarding the update method is unreliable, the database still has to update it row-by-row based on physical ordering(I sort the table by ID before inserting it to temporary table), so that's still reliable as reliable gets. Otherwise we can use cursor approach, a good starting point is from the article of Adam Machanic I posted on the question's comment

Comment: I am not convinces that `the database still has to update it row-by-row based on physical ordering`, sorry. It's possible that, in order to achieve better performance, the optimiser will prescribe a different order of updating than how rows are physically stored in the table. However, I'm ready to accept that your statement may be true on relatively small datasets. It would still be nice to have a more or less authoritative confirmation for that. (If you've done one hundred thousand quirky updates on small tables and never encountered an issue, that would be authoritative enough for me. ;)

Comment: @AndriyM I updated my answer to put a guard clause, check the er.. UPDATE ;-) I don't think there's a way for Sql Server to parallelize an inherently sequential code(variable assignment), so I think the `@RN_Check` is good enough to check against such anomaly ツ

Comment: I think I'll still have my reserves against the idea of quirky updates in general, for the time being, but that has nothing to do with the fact that you've done a tremendous job answering the OP's question. Well done and thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I remake the running total queries to include a partition (on Customer)

CTE approach:

```
with T AS
(
    select 
       ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CustomerCode order by OrderID) as rn, * 
    from test
)
,R(CustomerCode, Rn, OrderId, Qty, RunningTotal) as
(
    select CustomerCode, Rn, OrderID, Qty, Qty
    from t 
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select t.CustomerCode, t.Rn, t.OrderId, t.Qty, p.RunningTotal + t.Qty
    from t t
    join r p on p.CustomerCode = t.CustomerCode and t.rn = p.rn + 1

)
select R.CustomerCode, R.OrderId, R.Qty, R.RunningTotal from r
order by R.CustomerCode, R.OrderId 
option(maxrecursion 0);
```

Quirky update approach:

```
create function TestRunningTotalGuarded()
returns @ReturnTable table(
    CustomerCode varchar(50), OrderId int, Qty int, 
    RunningTotal int not null, RN int identity(1,1) not null
)
as begin

    insert into @ReturnTable(CustomerCode, OrderID, Qty, RunningTotal)
    select CustomerCode, OrderID, Qty, 0 from Test
    order by CustomerCode, OrderID;

    declare @RunningTotal int;

    declare @RN_check INT = 0;
    declare @PrevCustomerCode varchar(50) = NULL;

    update @ReturnTable set
            @RN_check = @RN_check + 1,
            @RunningTotal = 
                (case when RN = @RN_check then
                    case when @PrevCustomerCode = CustomerCode then
                        @RunningTotal + Qty 
                    else
                        Qty
                    end
                else
                    1/0 
                end),
            @PrevCustomerCode = CustomerCode,
            RunningTotal = @RunningTotal;

    return;
end;
```

Cursor approach (code compacted to remove the scrollbars)

```
create function TestRunningTotalCursor()
returns @ReturnTable table(CustomerCode varchar(50), OrderId int, 
                           Qty int, RunningTotal int not null) as
begin     
    declare @c_CustomerCode varchar(50);
    declare @c_OrderID int;
    declare @c_qty int;

    declare @PrevCustomerCode varchar(50) = null;
    declare @RunningTotal int = 0;

    declare o_cur cursor for
    select CustomerCode, OrderID, Qty from Test order by CustomerCode, OrderID;     
    open o_cur;
    fetch next from o_cur into @c_CustomerCode, @c_OrderID, @c_Qty;

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin

        if @c_CustomerCode = @PrevCustomerCode begin
            set @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + @c_qty;
        end else begin
            set @RunningTotal = @c_Qty;
        end;

        set @PrevCustomerCode = @c_CustomerCode;

        insert into @ReturnTable(CustomerCode, OrderId, Qty, RunningTotal)
        values(@c_CustomerCode, @c_OrderID, @c_Qty, @RunningTotal);

        fetch next from o_cur into @c_CustomerCode, @c_OrderID, @c_Qty;
    end;

    close o_cur; deallocate o_cur; return;
end;
```

Metrics on 5,000 rows:

```
* Recursive CTE : 49 seconds
* Quirky Update : 0 second
* Cursor        : 0 second
```

Those 0 seconds are not meaningful. After I bumped the rows to 50,000, here are the metrics:

```
* Quirky Update : 1 second
* Cursor        : 3 second
* Recursive CTE : An hour
```

Caveat, I [found out](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/05/recursive-cte-is-evil-and-cursor-is.html) that quirky update is really quirky, sometimes it works, sometime it don't(indicated by the presence of divide-by-zero error on one out five running of the query).

---

Here's the DDL for data:

```
create table Test(
    OrderID int primary key,
    CustomerCode varchar(50),
    Qty int not null
);


declare @i int = 1;

while @i <= 20 begin
    insert into Test(OrderID, CustomerCode, Qty) values (
        @i * 2
        ,case @i % 4 
        when 0 then 'JOHN'
        when 1 then 'PAUL'
        when 2 then 'GEORGE'
        when 3 then 'RINGO'
        end
        ,rand() * 10);    
    set @i = @i + 1;
end;
```

---

**UPDATE**

Apparently, the pure CTE approach is not good. Must use a hybrid approach. When the row numbering is materialized to an actual table, the speed goes up

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CustomerCode order by OrderID) as rn, * into #xxx 
from test;

with T AS
(
    select * from #xxx
)
,R(CustomerCode, Rn, OrderId, Qty, RunningTotal) as
(
    select CustomerCode, Rn, OrderID, Qty, Qty
    from t 
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select t.CustomerCode, t.Rn, t.OrderId, t.Qty, p.RunningTotal + t.Qty
    from t t
    join r p on p.CustomerCode = t.CustomerCode and t.rn = p.rn + 1

)
select R.CustomerCode, R.OrderId, R.Qty, R.RunningTotal from r
order by R.CustomerCode, R.OrderId 
option(maxrecursion 0);

drop table #xxx;
```

To recap, here are the metrics prior to converting the pure CTE to use materialized row numbering(row numbered results is in actual table, i.e. in temporary table)

```
* Quirky Update       : 1 second
* Cursor              : 3 second
* Recursive CTE(Pure) : An hour
```

After materializing the row numbering to temporary table:

```
* Quirky Update         : 1 second
* Cursor                : 3 second
* Recursive CTE(Hybrid) : 2 second (inclusive of row numbering table materialization)
```

Hybrid recursive CTE approach is actually faster than cursor approach.

---

**Another UPDATE**

Just by putting a clustered primary key on sequential column, the UPDATE update rows on its *physical* ordering. There's no more divide-by-zero(guard clause to detect non-sequential update) occurring. e.g.

```
alter function TestRunningTotalGuarded()
returns @ReturnTable table(
    CustomerCode varchar(50), OrderId int, Qty int, 
    RunningTotal int not null, 
    RN int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
)
```

I tried running the quirky update(with clustered primary key in place) 100 times if there could be corner cases, I found none so far. I haven't encounter any divide-by-zero error. Read the conclusion at the bottom of this blog post: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/05/recursive-cte-is-evil-and-cursor-is.html

And it's still fast even with clustered primary key in place.

Here's the metric for 100,000 rows:

```
Quirky Update        : 3 seconds
Hybrid Recursive CTE : 5 seconds
Cursor               : 6 seconds
```

Quirky update(which is not so quirky after all) is still fast. It's faster than hybrid recursive CTE.