# MySQL SUM with same ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the real simple question, I just learn PHP & MySQL, I already googling it for more than a week but I didn't found any answer.

I create a simple finance script and the table is like below :

```
table_a
aid | value
1   | 100
2   | 50
3   | 150

table_b
bid | aid | value
1   | 1   | 10
2   | 1   | 15
3   | 2   | 5
4   | 2   | 10
5   | 3   | 25
6   | 3   | 40
```

I want the result like this

```
No | ID | Total | Balance
1  | 1  | 10    | 90
2  | 1  | 25    | 75
3  | 2  | 5     | 45
4  | 2  | 15    | 35
5  | 3  | 25    | 125
6  | 3  | 65    | 85
```

Can anybody help me with my problem?

Thanks

Comment: What's the calculation to get the Balance value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   tb.bid as No,
   ta.aid as ID,
   tb.value as Total,
   ta.value-tb.total as Balance
FROM
  table_a AS ta
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      tbx.aid AS aid,
      tbx.bid AS bid,
      tbx.value AS value,
      SUM(tby.value) AS total
    FROM 
      table_b AS tbx
      INNER JOIN table_b AS tby ON tby.aid=tbx.aid AND tby.bid<=tbx.bid
    GROUP BY tbx.bid
    ORDER BY tbx.bid
  ) AS tb ON tb.aid=ta.aid
ORDER BY tb.bid
```

As @Quassnoi pointed out, this is not very efficient with MySQL. I tried to use a freak join instead of a subquery, as the inner query might be of use in its own right.

**Edit**

Took some interest in this and found  the join version to be twice as fast as the subquery version by @Quassnoi ... anybody having an idea why this would be?

**Edit**

Answer to the second question (in comment below):

```
SELECT
  table_a.aid AS aid,
  SUM(table_b.value) AS Total,
  table_a.value-SUM(table_b.value) AS Balance
FROM
  table_a
  INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.aid=table_b.aid
GROUP BY table_a.aid
```

Comment: Hi sir, sorry to disturb you again. How if I wanna make another page like this [aid|Total|Balance: Value 1|25|75 2|15|35 3|65|85]. Thanks

Comment: This is not a good answer, this will be ***very slow*** even on few rows. Even if you just have 1,000 rows, it will result to back-and-forth of 500,500 rows. 2,000 rows will result to 2 million and a thousand rows.  I'm a fan of this article: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-redux.aspx

Comment: Updated my answer with this second question

Comment: @MichaelBuen This is exactly why Quassnoi and I both pointed out, that this is not efficient - it still is the best answer to the OQ I can think of. I personally would create the table in the surrounding environment (PHP?), not SQL - but this is what was asked.

Comment: By the way, if you want an automatic creation of DDL based on sample data, just copy the OP's sample data. Then paste it to http://sqlfiddle.com **Text to DDL** ツ

Comment: Wow, great.. Thanks for your Help Mr. Eugen.. You save my day :D

Comment: Mysql don't have windowing functions (aka analytics functions) yet, but it has one good redeeming factor, variables ツ And a really good one at that, its inline variables is even way better than [Sql Server's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710995/can-this-recursive-solution-be-written-up-into-a-t-sql-query-using-cte-or-over/10712693#10712693). MySQL variables in action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842885/mysql-grouping-while-a-value-is-in-a-range/10843237#10843237

Comment: Hi, I hope you still there and read this comment, actually the table not that simple, but since I want to make it quick, I simplify it. And when I apply your code I feel so dizzy. I hope you can help me once more. Here are the more complex table : 
[table_a :"aid"|Out|Sout|Comp|Comp-detail|subcomp|subcomp-detail|account|account|detail|"value"] when in the previous question I just state "aid" dan "value". Continued below..

Comment: Cont..  How to show the other collumn of table_a, in the first question[No|AID|Out|Sout|Comp|Comp-detail|subcomp|subcomp-detail|account|account|detail|Value|Total|Balance] and in the second question [Aid|Out|Sout|Comp|Comp-detail|subcomp|subcomp-detail|account|account|detail|Total|Balance]
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this running total: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce765/1

```
select  
    bid as no, value,
    @rt := if(aid = @last_id, @rt + value, value) as total,
    @last_id := aid
from table_b b, (select @rt := 0 as x, @last_id := null) as vars
order by b.bid, b.aid;
```

Output:

```
| NO | VALUE | TOTAL | @LAST_ID := AID |
|----|-------|-------|-----------------|
|  1 |    10 |    10 |               1 |
|  2 |    15 |    25 |               1 |
|  3 |     5 |     5 |               2 |
|  4 |    10 |    15 |               2 |
|  5 |    25 |    25 |               3 |
|  6 |    40 |    65 |               3 |
```

Then join to table A, final query:

```
select x.no, x.aid, x.value, x.total, a.value - x.total as balance
from
(
  select    
    bid as no, aid, value,
    @rt := if(aid = @last_id, @rt + value, value) as total,
    @last_id := aid
  from table_b b, (select @rt := 0 as x, @last_id := null) as vars
  order by b.bid, b.aid
) as x
join table_a a using(aid)
```

Output:

```
| NO | AID | VALUE | TOTAL | BALANCE |
|----|-----|-------|-------|---------|
|  1 |   1 |    10 |    10 |      90 |
|  2 |   1 |    15 |    25 |      75 |
|  3 |   2 |     5 |     5 |      45 |
|  4 |   2 |    10 |    15 |      35 |
|  5 |   3 |    25 |    25 |     125 |
|  6 |   3 |    40 |    65 |      85 |
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce765/1

---

**UPDATE**

Not dependent on column **bid** sorting, running total on grouping will not be impacted: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a1e6/3

```
select x.no, x.aid, x.value, x.total, a.value - x.total as balance
from
(
  select    
    @rn := @rn + 1 as no, aid, value,
    @rt := if(aid = @last_id, @rt + value, value) as total,
    @last_id := aid
  from table_b b, (select @rt := 0 as x, @last_id := null, @rn := 0) as vars
  order by b.aid, b.bid
) as x
join table_a a using(aid)
```

Output:

```
| NO | AID | VALUE | TOTAL | BALANCE |
|----|-----|-------|-------|---------|
|  1 |   1 |    10 |    10 |      90 |
|  2 |   1 |    15 |    25 |      75 |
|  3 |   1 |     7 |    32 |      68 |
|  4 |   2 |     5 |     5 |      45 |
|  5 |   2 |    10 |    15 |      35 |
|  6 |   3 |    25 |    25 |     125 |
|  7 |   3 |    40 |    65 |      85 |
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a1e6/3

Comment: This answer has the big problem of producing incorrect results if the rows in table_b are not sorted by aid ... try `insert into table_b values (7,1,7);` and then again your query - last line will read `7/1/7/7/93` instead of `7/1/7/32/68`

Comment: @EugenRieck That can easily be rectified ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for analytics functions. Unfortunately, `MySQL` lacks them.

You can implement it in a less efficient way:

```
SELECT  bid, aid, total, value - total
FROM    (
        SELECT  b.bid, b.aid, COALESCE(a.value, 0) AS value,
                (
                SELECT  SUM(value)
                FROM    b bp
                WHERE   bp.aid = b.aid
                        AND bp.bid <= b.bid
                ) AS total
        FROM    b
        LEFT JOIN
                a
        ON      a.aid = b.aid
        ) q
```

Comment: You are missing a comma at the end of line 3

Comment: I try this but I got error message, so what is q in the last line?

Comment: I got this error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( SELECT SUM(value) FROM b bp ' at line 4: SELECT bid, aid, total, value - total FROM ( SELECT b.bid, b.aid, COALESCE(a.value, 0) AS value ( SELECT SUM(value) FROM b bp WHERE bp.aid = b.aid AND bp.bid <= b.bid ) AS total FROM b LEFT JOIN a ON a.aid = b.aid ) q